# Decrypt TrueCrypt WDE from another OS?

Tags: truecrypt

My HDD with Windows 7 on it and TrueCrypt whole disk encryption got corrupted. I am able to boot the disk, enter TC password and I get the black screen with Windows logo on it, but that's as far as it goes.

I have mounted the HDD as an external drive and am able to see it. The drive has 5 partitions - the first and last of them work OK (even though I can't start Windows which is on the first one), but the other 3 are missing and showing as Free Space.

Is there a way to decrypt the disk as a mounted external HDD from within another Windows installation as opposed to booting the HDD and using the Truecrypt Rescue Disk?

Comment: If you were using full disk encryption then you have already done what your asking about. The data is missing likely because the hdd failed and the MFT was corrupted.

Comment: I was able to mount the first and last partitions, but I'd like to decrypt the whole disk so that I could try to recover data from the 2nd, 3rd, 4th partitions. Is there any other way to do this while the disk is still encrypted?

Comment: You would have to restore their partition information for those partitions from a previous image of the HDD since they currently are not even being identified as being partitions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what an "image" of the HDD is, but unless it's something that's automatically kept as a backup on the HDD I haven't created any backup images. Back to my main question - is there a way to decrypt the HDD as mounted external drive or do I have to boot it and use TRD?